# spi5 of my STM32MP157F-K2 CAN'T read data from the RC522 CARD

Tags: stm32, rfid, stm32cubeide

i was trying to connect the rfid card to spi5 of the stm32MP157 since im a totally beginner in the cube ide i had a problem to understand the reasons. so i m gonna share with u the clock configuration and the spi5 configuration plus the rc522.c related to my code
spi5

```
 hspi5.Instance = SPI5;
  hspi5.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi5.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi5.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi5.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi5.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi5.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_8;
  hspi5.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_LSB;
  hspi5.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.CRCPolynomial = 0x0;
  hspi5.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.NSSPolarity = SPI_NSS_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi5.Init.FifoThreshold = SPI_FIFO_THRESHOLD_01DATA;
  hspi5.Init.TxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
  hspi5.Init.RxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
  hspi5.Init.MasterSSIdleness = SPI_MASTER_SS_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
  hspi5.Init.MasterInterDataIdleness = SPI_MASTER_INTERDATA_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
  hspi5.Init.MasterReceiverAutoSusp = SPI_MASTER_RX_AUTOSUSP_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.MasterKeepIOState = SPI_MASTER_KEEP_IO_STATE_DISABLE;
  hspi5.Init.IOSwap = SPI_IO_SWAP_DISABLE;
```

clock configuration

```
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_MEDIUMHIGH);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_CSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI
                              |RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_BYPASS_DIG;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDivValue = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.CSIState = RCC_CSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLSource = RCC_PLL12SOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLM = 3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLN = 66;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLQ = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLR = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLFRACV = 0x1400;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL2.PLLMODE = RCC_PLL_FRACTIONAL;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLSource = RCC_PLL3SOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLM = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLN = 56;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLP = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLQ = 50;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLR = 37;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL3IFRANGE_1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLFRACV = 4096;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL3.PLLMODE = RCC_PLL_FRACTIONAL;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLSource = RCC_PLL4SOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLM = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLN = 99;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLP = 6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLQ = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLR = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL4IFRANGE_0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLFRACV = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL4.PLLMODE = RCC_PLL_INTEGER;
```

main code

```
HAL_Delay(1000);
       status = MFRC522_Request(PICC_REQIDL, str);
        status = MFRC522_Anticoll(str);
        memcpy(sNum, str, 5);
        HAL_Delay(100);

        // Print out the entire str array
        printf("Received data: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            printf("%02X ", str[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        // Print out individual bytes
        printf("Byte 0: %02X\n", str[0]);
        printf("Byte 1: %02X\n", str[1]);
        // Repeat for other bytes...

        if((str[0]==115) && (str[1]==93) && (str[2]==75) && (str[3]==22) && (str[4]==115))
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_7, 0);
            HAL_Delay(100);
        }
        else if((str[0]==199) && (str[1]==102) && (str[2]==209) && (str[3]==215) && (str[4]==167))
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_7, 0);
            HAL_Delay(2000);
        }
        else
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH, GPIO_PIN_7, 1);
        }
```

function transmit data in rc522.c

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef RC522_SPI_Transmit(uint8_t data) {
    return HAL_SPI_Transmit(HSPI_INSTANCE, &data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

// Function to receive data over SPI
HAL_StatusTypeDef RC522_SPI_Receive(uint8_t *rx_data) {
    return HAL_SPI_Receive(HSPI_INSTANCE, rx_data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

// Combined function to transmit and receive data over SPI
uint8_t RC522_SPI_Transfer(uint8_t data) {
    uint8_t rx_data;

    // Transmit data
    if (RC522_SPI_Transmit(data) != HAL_OK) {
        // Handle transmit error
        return 0; // Or any error handling mechanism you prefer
    }

    // Receive data
    if (RC522_SPI_Receive(&rx_data) != HAL_OK) {
        // Handle receive error
        return 0; // Or any error handling mechanism you prefer
    }

    return rx_data;
}
```

Read_MFRC522

```
uchar Read_MFRC522(uchar addr)
{
    uchar data = 0x00;
    uchar val = 0x00;
    /* CS LOW */
//  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG,3,GPIO_PIN_RESET);

      // even though we are calling transfer frame once, we are really sending
      // two 8-bit frames smooshed together-- sending two 8 bit frames back to back
      // results in a spike in the select line which will jack with transactions
      // - top 8 bits are the address. Per the spec, we shift the address left
      //   1 bit, clear the LSb, and set the MSb to indicate a read
      // - bottom 8 bits are all 0s on a read per 8.1.2.1 Table 6
    RC522_SPI_Transfer(((addr<<1)&0x7E) | 0x80);
    HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(HSPI_INSTANCE,&data,&val,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
//  val = RC522_SPI_Transfer(0x00);

    /* CS HIGH */
//  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG,3,GPIO_PIN_SET);

    return val;

}
```

i double checked the wiring even i tried to use spi4 and it didn't work  i tried fix the baud rate to 9Mbites also i changed the spi and the clock configuration still there are no data to read i have been stuck in here for a while know i want know if anyone have faced the same problem before ? is it a problem with the spi ? or the configuration ? or the function RC522_SPI_Transfer ?

Comment: Hi, I'd like to be able to help, but I don't understand what's going wrong. There's lots of ways that SPI transfers can fail, and giving more information about what happens other than "it didn't work" would help narrow down the problem.  Also please [read this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help asking a question

Comment: im sorry for not being clear in my question because i said before i'am new in here and in this but i mean when i debug  the main  code, the function MFRC522_Request can't read the card  i got 0 in the live expression

Comment: Right, I see that you're new here, but I want to emphasize that its easier to help answer with more specific details. "i got 0" means what? Which variable is 0? What did you expect to happen? Were the functions in `Read_MFRC522()` commented out?

Are you able to observe the physical lines from the STM32 chip with a logic analyzer? That would at least help rule out a problem with the pin configuration

Comment: Your `RC522_SPI_Transfer()` function return a value of `rx_data`, but you are simple ignore it with `RC522_SPI_Transfer(((addr<<1)&0x7E) | 0x80);`, you then send a byte of 0 with `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(HSPI_INSTANCE,&data,&val,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);`, what exactly you are expecting the chip to return from that? Read the data sheet and understand what command to send to the chip in order to get back the data.

Comment: The easier way to test if your SPI settings are correct an be able to read something from the chip is to send address 0x37h (for reading the VersionReg, see datasheet and search for VersionReg) to the chip and if you can read back the value of 0x91h or 0x92h, then you can proceed to write your code for reading the rest of data.

Comment: hey  hcheung  thank u for the a advice . can u explain to me what do u mean by send adress 0x37h exactly ?

Comment: GandhiGandhi okay when i debug i put the card to read in this line     status = MFRC522_Request(PICC_REQIDL, str);
 and i press step into i go to uchar MFRC522_Request(uchar reqMode, uchar *TagType)
{
 uchar status;
 uint backBits;    // The received data bits

 Write_MFRC522(BitFramingReg, 0x07);  //TxLastBists = BitFramingReg[2..0]

 TagType[0] = reqMode;
 status = MFRC522_ToCard(PCD_TRANSCEIVE, TagType, 1, TagType, &backBits);

 if ((status != MI_OK) || (backBits != 0x10))
 {
  status = MI_ERR;
 }

 return status;
}
that functions returns MI_ERR